# How to SSH Quorum running on Azure VMs?

Tags: quorum, console, microsoft-azure

I have deployed a `Quorum` Network on `Azure` and now I would like to have ssh access. In the creation process I had to set a `VM-user` and a `VM-password`. But if I use them like this:

`ssh VM-user@Public-IP-address`

I get this:

`ssh: connect to host <ip_adress> port 22: Connection timed out`

Does anybody know how use `ssh` with `Azure` and `Quorum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do it.

On your portal page (https://portal.azure.com/#) go to:

1. `Resource groups`
2. Choose your group
3. Go to `Deployments`
4. Under deployment name click on the name, which looks something like this: `enterprise-ethereum-alliance.eea-single-member-20181234567890`
5. In the left menu click `Outputs`
6. There you have it, under `SSH-TO-FIRST-VM`.

It looks something like this:

`ssh -p 3000 youradminname@yourname.yourlocation.cloudapp.azure.com`